Traffic Routing with different EC2 same public subnet in AWS
What is the best approach to implement High Availability (HA) for traffic failover/switchover during disaster recovery between two public subnets containing EC2 instances with Strongswan on AWS , in same region and same AZ ?
Detail Description :
I am working on setting up High Availability (HA) , the goal is to ensure that if one EC2 instance in Public Subnet 1 becomes unavailable, the traffic will automatically failover to another EC2 instance running in Public Subnet 2, both of which are configured with Strongswan for VPN connectivity.

To implement HA with traffic failover between Public Subnet 1 and Public Subnet 2 in AWS, the recommended solution involves , combination of :
Elastic Load Balancer (ALB/NLB) for distributing traffic across EC2 instances in both public subnets and performing health checks to ensure only healthy instances receive traffic.
Route 53 for DNS-based failover. This ensures that traffic is routed to healthy subnets based on health checks, providing fault tolerance for your infrastructure.

To achieve high availability (HA) and enable traffic failover between two public subnets hosting EC2 instances with HA, you can utilize an Application Load Balancer (ALB).
Start by creating a target group and registering both EC2 instances (one in each subnet) as targets.
Next, configure an ALB to distribute incoming traffic across these targets. The ALB operates across multiple Availability Zones, ensuring failover by directing traffic to the healthy instance in the event of failure in one subnet. Additionally, configure health checks in the target group to monitor the EC2 instances’ availability and functionality, allowing the ALB to dynamically route traffic to the active instance. This setup ensures continuous traffic flow and enhances application reliability during subnet or instance failures.
these links have all the informations you need:
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html
